# Export tcpdump capture output to json

Tags: tcpdump

I need to export a capture output in `json ek` (for elasticsearch) format.
I can't use another program like `wireshark` or `tshark`. I just can use an implementation of `tcpdump 4.9.2` (pf_ring implementation for those who know it).

I'm thinking about inspiring myself on `tshark` code for exporting to `json ek` and reimplementing this functionality on `tcpdump`.

My question, and what I need help with is:

- Is this viable?
- How much time would it take approximately if I'm alone programming
  and I'm OK but not very good in C programming language?

Comment: Why not use packet beat directly ?   (or adapt it to your need if needed)

Comment: I didn't know that software of `elastic.co`. Seems so interesting. Do you know if it's compatible with `pf_ring capture modules` ?

Comment: It's no longer compatible with `pf_ring`. It's mandatory that I use this capture software :(

Comment: Take the previous version then ;)   anyway you will have to recompile it

Comment: That sounds good. I'm trying it!